# Image Processing Exam Paper Java OCR

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am new to `image processing` and `opencv`. I am currently trying to create a java application where the user inputs marked exam paper and process it.

Below is a sample of a paper (right side)

[image: The paper]

On the right side of the paper it has the marks for a question and the total marks he/she can get. What i am trying to do is that if the left side box has 3 marks written in pen after processing, it i should know its number 3. If there is a [✓] he/she should get full marks. There will be many boxes like this in one page. I must then add all and show total marks. 
 I am wondering how to implement this, any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried using `PDF` format?

Comment: no, im getting started on this application, need ideas or help

Comment: if I get your needs well, **you need an editable graphic document with input fields.** Right? You only need checkboxes or you will also need to fill texts?

Comment: no, the exam paper is already marked, the box will have mark (eg;3) or a ✓ i must identify them from the right side of the paper and calculate the marks (the marks which he/she has got) and give the total.

Comment: uhmmmm... ok... so I guess `PDF` is NOT your sollution...

Comment: As with most image analysis applications, you have to break down your problem into subproblems: (1) locating the boxes (2) locating which boxes should be evaluated (3) identifying the character in the box (4) locating the existence of check-mark. Also as with most image analysis applications, you can **substantially** simplify your problem by good design of the areas around your region of interest, e.g. with registration marks or alternative ways of user input; for example by not a ✓, but by the user filling in a box.

Comment: i should crop the image and get the box sides first?